# VS Code Python Debugger Conditional Statement Not Working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, package, vscode-debugger

I am trying to get the debugger to have a breakpoint whenever theres a caught, or uncaught exception, only on the package I am developing. I am using the below code for a conditional breakpoint. Note that the modules in the package are importing inspect.

`"mypythonpackage" in str(inspect.getmodule(inspect.trace()[-1][0]))`

This is not triggering a breakpoint in the debugger. What could be wrong here?

Comment: does it break if you make a simpler expression

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT The code is already provided? You can just run this on anything.

Comment: import mypythonpackage; mypythonpackage.myclass.mystaticmethod()

Comment: @rioV8 no, it does not :/

Comment: if `mypythonpackage` imports `inspect` it does not mean it is known global when you import `mypythonpackage`, thus the expression generates an exception

Comment: @rioV8 inspect is imported into the module with the code that should be breaking